# django url how to use questions mark? (class based views)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

in my URL for the createview, I want there to be a '?', from where I can pass an argument to the nect page. I am using class based views. For example:

www.site.com/appname/appointment/add/?Name=1

And my HTML would be:

```
href={% url 'People:appointment-create' Patient.id %}
```

Currently my URL is like so:

```
re_path(r'appointment/add/$', views.appointmentCreate.as_view(), name='appointment-create'),
```

and my view is:

```
class appointmentCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = appointment
    form_class = AppointmentForm

    def get_initial(self):
        patient = self.request.GET.get('patient')
        return {
            'Patient': patient,
        }
```

How would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
href={% url 'People:appointment-create' %}?patient_id={{ Patient.id }}
```

(so just pass the query arguments after the url as normally).

Also, if you want a more general solution on this problem (automatically generate the form's initial values from query parameters) take a look at this section https://spapas.github.io/#configure-the-form-s-initial-values-from-get-parameters from by article on CBVs.

Answer (score 1):

So here's the basics:

first of all I would like to let you know about below line you just wrote:

```
{% url 'People:appointment-create' Patient.id %}
```

to match above url you will need to include below url:

```
path(r'appointment/add/<int:patient>', views.appointmentCreate.as_view(), name='appointment-create'),
```

This is the difference between request parameters and kwargs here you pass patient id as kwargs and access in Class base view in `self.kwargs`

The constructed url will be like below:

```
www.site.com/appname/appointment/add/1/
```

Next thing is that if you want to post request parameter (which don't require to add any additional url in your urls.py) you can use as below:

```
href="{% url 'People:appointment-create' %}?patient={{Patient.id}}"
```

Note that the parameter you use here will be available in view if you use name in request parameter then you need to access it as `self.request.GET.get('name')` and if you want to use patient as request parameter then you can access it as `self.request.GET.get('patient')`.